# Move row form table to another with additional data

Tags: mysql

I have tow tables look similar to these tables

**Members**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
    `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Archived Members**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `archived_members` (
    `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `archived_date` timestamp NOT NULL,
    `archived_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=ARCHIVE DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

I usually use this query statement to move rows between tables ***THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE***

```
INSERT INTO `archived_members` (`ID`, `email`, `password`) SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `ID`=1;
DELETE FROM `members` WHERE `ID`=1;
```

But in my case(this case) I have to specify values for the other field in `archived_members` table which are `archived_date` & `archived_type`. Therefore, I tried

```
INSERT INTO `archived_members` (`ID`, `email`, `password`) SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `ID`=1;
UPDATE `archived_members` SET `archived_date`=CURRENT_DATE(), `archived_type`='reason of archving' WHERE `ID`=1;
DELETE FROM `members` WHERE `ID`=1;
```

Unfortunately, the engine of `archived_members` table is ***ARCHIVE*** as I think it should be, so I cannot update the rows after they are inserted to the table.

PLEASE, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
INSERT INTO `archived_members` (`ID`, `email`, `password`,`archived_date`,`archived_type`) SELECT m.*, CURRENT_DATE(), 'reason of archving' FROM `members` m WHERE `ID`=1;
DELETE FROM `members` WHERE `ID`=1;
```

I didn't tested but I'm pretty sure this can work.

Answer (score 0):

You know that `SELECT * FROM...` is not the only way to write a `SELECT` statement, right?

```
INSERT INTO `archived_members` 
 (`ID`, `email`, `password`, `archived_date`, `archived_type` ) 
SELECT 
 `ID`, `email`, `password`, CURRENT_DATE(), 'reason of archving' 
FROM `members` WHERE `ID`=1;
```